# Using EntityManager.getReference() with natural key

Tags: java, jpa

I have two entity types Log and LogType defined like so:

```
public class LogType {

    @Id @NotNull
    private Short id;

    @Size(max = 30) @Column(name = "LOG_TYPE")
    private String type;

    /* More fields, getters and setters */

}
public class Log {

    @Id @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "LOG_TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "LOG_TYPE")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private LogType type;

    /* More fields, getters and setters */

}
```

The LOG_TYPE.LOG_TYPE field is a text string identifier that serves as a natural key separate from the primary key.  Is there any way to use this natural key with EntityManager.getReference() to prevent a database call to pull the LogType when saving a record?  If not, is there a way to duplicate the functionality of getReference in order to save the value in the LOG table without loading the full type?